Weird bug regarding ts path aliases and vite
im using react & ts & vite combo, I encounter a problem where when I run
npm run dev 

I get the following error:
The requested module '/src/components/ui/index.ts' does not provide an export named 'SquareButton'
This is my index.ts file:

export * from "./input";
export * from "./button";
export * from "./checkbox";
export * from "./phone-input";
export * from "./separator";
export * from "./select";
export * from "./label";
export * from "./otp";
export * from "./date-picker";
export * from "./time-picker";

And this is the import:

import { SquareButton } from "@components/ui";

I found a way to temporary fix is, and it's by simply  swapping lines in the index.ts file, for exmaple I move line 10 to line 9, and line 9 to line 10, this problem is really weird since my ts path alias obviously is working, it's like vite doesn't seem to know that the file exists until I update it, first time ever encountering this problem.

Is that a compile or run time error? In the latter case, it might be a problem caused by a circular dependency.

its a runtime error I think but if its caused by a circular dependency, why would it be fixed if i simply move random lines in the file?

I got more info, when I inspect in the source tab, I see that the file is empty (the index.ts file), so like the component logic is running but the not all the files are loaded, when Im changing the index.ts files its all loading successfully

That's kind of funny, but clearing the chrome cache and doing hard reload solved the problem
